# How to print POSTed json on html in Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

here is my `index.html` javascript:

```
$('#clickme').bind('click',function(){

 var url = "/lms/quizes/show/";
        var data = {"size": "width=8, height=9", "weight": "8 kg", "desc": "'&='"};
        var string_data = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        });
})
```

here is my views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def show(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print 'Raw Data: "%s"' % request.body   
    return HttpResponse(request, content_type="application/json")
```

I want to post a json to a url `show.html`, but right now I can only see the json in my console log.

Comment: For starters, just return `request.body` instead of `OK`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Try

```
return HttpResponse(request, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: @ Zach Spencer It only show the data in index.html's console, but not print in show.html

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you need, I am sorry.